# AVPlayer Progress slider change with user dragging it

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am using AVPlayer, and its working good.

I put slider and it is progression according to player duration. 
But i want if user drags slider then play time changes accordingly. i.e. Song forwards or backwards according to slider position.

I have tried

```
-(IBAction)sliderChange:(id)sender{
[player pause];
CMTime t = CMTimeMake(slider.value,1);
[player seekToTime:t];    
[player play];
}
```

But it again takes slider to starting point. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT (WORKING WITH BELOW LINK)

[AVPlayer Video SeekToTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329706/avplayer-video-seektotime)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
-(IBAction) valueChangeSliderTimer:(id)sender{
    [avplayer pause];
    isPlaying = FALSE;
    [btnPauseAndPlay setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    float timeInSecond = sliderTimer.value;

    timeInSecond *= 1000;
    CMTime cmTime = CMTimeMake(timeInSecond, 1000);

    [avplayer seekToTime:cmTime toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];
}
```

Edited Code .

And try this link as well :
[Try this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329706/avplayer-video-seektotime)

Comment: Thank you so much for answer but could you please check it again because in my question i wrote i am implementing AVPlayer not AVAudioPlayer. setCurrentTime is not visible for AVPlayer. Thanks

Comment: With this code when i touch slider then it starts from starting. it reaches at starting point.

Comment: Pause your player ,when you change the value of slider,fetch the latest value of slider and try implementing this method

'-(void) sliderTimerChange{
    
    CMTime time = [queuePlayer currentTime];
 if (CMTIME_IS_VALID(time) && isPlaying) {
  [self showTimeOnScroll:time];
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(sliderTimerChange) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]; 
 }
 else {
  NSLog(@"time is invalid");
 }    
    
}'

Comment: it shows error  [self showTimeOnScroll:time];  on which object shall i call this method?

Comment: and i am binding slider method with valueChanged in IB not with touchupinside. Am i right?

Comment: Yeah,slider changes is to be bind with valuechanged only,its right,the method you getting crash is
`-(void) showTimeOnScroll:(CMTime)time{
    
 float timeOriginal = CMTimeGetSeconds(time); 
 sliderTimer.value = timeOriginal;
 
}`

Comment: here is complete handling code.  http://paste.org/50513 Please note in sliderTimerChange method i am using player.rate!=0 instead of isPlaying . because isPlaying dont work on AVPlayer. But again it is creating problem

Comment: isPlaying is just bool variable i used,it checks if current state is playing or paused,wait let me give you in brief.

Comment: please check my complete code. i am progressing slider in other method.

Comment: Are you using any button to handle play and pause state?

Comment: Yes two buttons , one  for [player play ]; and other for [player pause];

Comment: I have written complete code in above link in my Edited  question before. I guess it will help you to trace problem

Comment: http://paste.org/50518 check this,i wrote brief code,you can handle the bool variable,that is ,on Sliding pause the track and make isPlaying = False,and while playing make it True,it should work now. :)

Comment: No first of all when i click play button then slider goes to extreem right. i.e 100% played status

Comment: @mann : Are you still facing problem,i was searching for something that can be helpful to you.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329706/avplayer-video-seektotime]