# How to set current time and total time for a song in AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, nstimer, uislider, avplayer

I want to use the following code in my application to get the current playing time and total time on a UISlider and i get ths code from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329706/avplayer-video-seektotime).

```
   -(IBAction)sliding:(id)sender{

    CMTime newTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seeker.value, 1);
    [self.player seekToTime:newTime];
 }

-(void)setSlider{

    sliderTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self    selector:@selector(updateSlider) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]retain];
    self.seeker.maximumValue = [self durationInSeconds];
    [seeker addTarget:self action:@selector(sliding:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    seeker.minimumValue = 0.0;
    seeker.continuous = YES;  
}

- (void)updateSlider {

    self.seeker.maximumValue = [self durationInSeconds];
    self.seeker.value = [self currentTimeInSeconds];
}

- (Float64)durationInSeconds {
        Float64 dur = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
    return dur;
}


- (Float64)currentTimeInSeconds {
        Float64 dur = CMTimeGetSeconds([self.player currentTime]);
    return dur;
  }
```

But I don't know what is *seeker*. I am new in iOS and i need help any suggestion any tutorial for this problem.

Comment: how to set time in UILABEL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *seeker;
```

Comment: how to set time in UILABEL? @ZGl6YXNt

Answer (score 0):

@Mr.Bond

```
- (Float64)currentTimeInSeconds {

double runningTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(_playerViewController.player.currentTime);
NSLog(@"currentTime %f",runningTime);

return dur;
}
```